# Race conditions

Tags: race-condition, circuit, digital-logic, circuit-diagram

I'm currently stuck trying to understand two things related to race conditions.

**Issue 1:**

I have been presented with the following question:

```
We consider the digital circuit and the value of its inputs a,
and b as given below. For all logic gates, we assume that
there is a gate delay of exactly one time unit (i.e. the gate
delay equals the time between two dotted lines in the
diagram). Give the values of c, d, e, f in the digital circuit for
every point of time between 0 and 8.
```

[image]

And the answer given is as follows:

[image]

How exactly is this achieved? This is what I think so far:

- **c** starts at 1 because **a** start at 0
- **d** starts at 0 because **b** start at 1
- When time is equal to 2 **a** becomes 1... there is a propogation delay of 1 for **c** to switch over to 0 hence it becomes 0 at 3 time units
- Same logic applies to **d**
- **e** and **f** are meant to be constant 1 or 0 but seem to be affected by something.

What's really going on here? Is it related to a boolean function or soemthing. If so what?

**Issue 2:**

Does anyone have a simple way or logical approach in which to produce a simple circuit (using XOR, AND, OR, NOT, NAND boolean functions with:

- static race condition - when the value is meant to be constant
- dynamic race condition - when a value is expected to change

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hans haha it's revision for an Computer Science exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so race conditions in asynchronous circuits happen when inputs change at different times  for a gate. Let's say your logical function looks like this

```
λ = ab + ~b~a
```

the most straightforward way to implement this function with gates looks like

**NOTE**: I assume your basic building blocks are AND, OR, and NOT. Obviously in CMOS circuits, NAND, NOR and NOT is how you build circuits, but the general principal stays the same. I also assume AND, NOR, and NOT have the same delay when in reality NAND and NOR have different delays if the output goes form `0 to 1` or `1 to 0`, and NOT is about 20% faster than NAND or NOR.

```
a ->| AND |-------->| OR | -> λ
b ->|  1  |         |    |
                    |    |
a ->| NOT |->|AND|->|    |
b ->| NOT |->| 2 |  |    |
```

Now, assume that AND and NOT both have a delay of 2ns. That means the OR gate sees the value at it's first position change 2 ns before it sees the value at its second position change.

Which means if `a` and `b` both go from `1` to `0`, you would expect `λ` to stay the same, since the output of the first AND gate is going from `1` to `0`, but the output of the AND gate goes from `0` to `1`, meaning the OR condition stays true.

However, if you get the output from the second AND gate a little bit after the first AND gate, then your OR gate will momentarily see `0,0` at it's input while transitioning from `1,0` to `0,1`. Which means `λ` will have a momentary dip and it'll look like

```
     __
   a   |___________
     __
   b   |___________
     ____
AND1     |_________
            _______
AND2 ______|
     ______   _____
   λ       |_|
```

If you look at the inputs of the OR gate right between when AND1 goes down and AND2 goes up, it propagates a `0` through the OR gate, and sure enough, there's a dip in the output 2ns later.

That's a general overview for how race conditions arise. Hope that helps you understand your question.

Comment: How would you read `λ = ab + ~b~a` - we've only been using AND, OR, NOT when naming our logical functions.

Comment: ab is equivalent to (a and b). The reasoning is if you take 0 to mean false and any other value to mean 1, then ab is 0 if either a and b is 0. a + b is equivalent to a or b. The reasoning is if either a or b are > 0, then a + b > 0. ~a is another way of writing not a. as is !a, -a, and a'.